# Meteor and semantic stackable grid

Tags: mobile, meteor, grid, semantic-ui

I am using Meteor and Semantic-ui 2 and can't get the stackable grid to work on mobile (iPhone 6). When I resize my computer screen everything works fine but not on the mobile. On the mobile I have 3 columns and space on the sides (just as a large screen). It should be stacked in one column and use 100% of the screen. As I can understand mobile is defined as below 768px and iPhone6 is 750px. Do anyone have any suggestions or answers to solve this?

```
    <div class="ui three column stackable grid container">
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="nine wide column"></div>
        <div class="three wide column"></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out as I asked a question on gitter.im
Since the header markup is mainly handled by Meteor I forgot to add the

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I added it in my layout template as I am using Iron Router at the top of the page and it worked